# Is there an ability to have a webserver combine responses for non-static requests?

Tags: html, webserver

Some time ago I read about some work done to cut down on the web client to web server chatter by combining client requests or server responses to help reduce latency.

Basically the web client would merge its requests into one larger request and/or the server could combine its responses to the webclient into one larger response.

The idea being to reduce chatter and latency in real time.

I am either searching for the wrong thing or just dreaming but my search attempts are coming up empty.

I ask as a developer because I would prefer to enable such a technology rather then having to manually code it myself.  We have an app that has the potential to be very chatty.

Search terms I tried are: Request Merging/Combining, Response Merging/Combining, Write Combining for Web, and many others...

Note: I am NOT taking about merging static JS/CSS or even Image files (sprites) at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [persistent connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) enables a client to send multiple requests over the socket. Other possibilities include [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) and/or [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

[image: HTTP Pipelining]